# Does a Type Rating "upgrade" with your license?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, type-ratings

I believe anything the FAA refers to as a "rating" *upgrades* automatically with your license. For example, if I get my instrument rating on my Private Pilot License, I don't have to retake the instrument checkride when I get my commercial license in order to fly IFR commercially. This is not true for license classes (single engine land, multi-engine land, single engine sea, multi-engine sea). If I get a private MEL, and then take my commercial checkride in a single engine, I still have to take another commercial MEL checkride in order to exercise commercial privileges in a multi-engine airplane.

The question is, do type ratings work like instrument ratings or like license classes, and what regulations govern this?

Comment: `I don't have to retake the instrument checkride when I get my commercial license`.  But you do have to demonstrate instrument tasks. If you don't, your licence will be limited to VFR only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to this lies in [8900.1, Volume 5, Chapter 2, Section 18 - Conduct an Airline Transport Pilot Certification, Including Additional Category/Class Ratings](http://fsims.faa.gov/WDocs/8900.1/V05%20Airman%20Cert/Chapter%2002/05_002_018Rev1.htm).

In most cases, yes the type rating "upgrades" or "elevates" along with your license since the type rating is always evaluated at ATP standards, even if you only have a private or commercial certificate.

Exceptions are type ratings for single-engine airplanes and type ratings that have a "VFR ONLY" restriction.

8900.1 excerpt:

> **5-710    PILOT CERTIFICATE LEVEL AND CATEGORY AND CLASS RATING.** The following category and class rating(s) for which the applicant has
>   qualified on the original or subsequent ATP practical tests are
>   entered on the ATP certificate.
>
> **A.    Addition of Lighter-than-Air and Glider Class Ratings.** A lighter-than-air or glider category rating may be added to an existing
>   ATP certificate; however, the rating may be added only at the
>   recreational, private, or commercial pilot certificate level, as
>   appropriate to the practical test completed. There is no provision for
>   the original issuance of an ATP certificate with a lighter-than-air or
>   glider category rating.
>
> **B.    Type Ratings.** Type rating tests are conducted to the ATP standard for all grades of pilot certificate. Therefore, all type
>   ratings in that category and class of aircraft for which the practical
>   test is conducted in are upgraded after successful completion of the
>   practical test. For example, a person who holds B-737, DC-3, and SK-62
>   type ratings on his or her commercial pilot certificate, and later
>   satisfactorily completes an ATP practical test in a CE-750, would have
>   his/her B-737 and DC-3 type ratings elevated up to the ATP
>   certificate. The SK-62 would not elevate up because the practical test
>   was in a multiengine airplane. However, when the person satisfactorily
>   completes an ATP practical test in a helicopter, the SK-62 would then
>   elevate up to the ATP certificate. Therefore, all of the type ratings
>   held on the superseded certificate carry forward at the new
>   certificate level within category and class.
>
> NOTE:  A type rating for a single-engine airplane may not be upgraded
>   to the ATP level.
>
> 1)    Except for type ratings and, under some circumstances, the
>   instrument rating, other ratings indicated on the superseded pilot
>   certificate are carried forward at the commercial, private, or
>   recreational pilot certificate level, as indicated on the superseded
>   certificate.
>
> 2)    Instrument rating privileges are shown on the ATP certificate
>   only if the ATP practical test was conducted under visual flight rules
>   (VFR) only, or to retain instrument privileges that were held on the
>   superseded certificate for a category of aircraft other than the one
>   used for the ATP practical test.
>
> **C.    Type Rating Limited to VFR.** A type rating bearing the limitation “VFR ONLY” may be added to an existing certificate other
>   than an ATP certificate under the provisions of § 61.63(e). This
>   limitation may be added to an aircraft type rating not capable of
>   instrument maneuvers or procedures required on a practical test. The
>   practical test must be administered under the appropriate ATP PTS for
>   an aircraft type rating limited to “VFR ONLY”. A type rating bearing
>   the limitation “VFR ONLY” may be added to an existing ATP certificate
>   under the provisions of § 61.157(g). The practical test must be
>   administered under the appropriate ATP PTS for an aircraft type rating
>   limited to “VFR ONLY.”
>
> NOTE:  There is no provision for taking an initial practical test for
>   an ATP certificate in an aircraft that would require a VFR limitation.

Comment: Apparently the FAA uses _both_ upgrade and elevate. "...for which the practical test is conducted in are __upgraded__ after successful completion..." and "would have his/her B-737 and DC-3 type ratings __elevated__ up to the ATP certificate."

Comment: Wow, they can't even stay consistent *in the same paragraph*!

Comment: "There is no provision for the original issuance of an ATP certificate with a lighter-than-air or glider category rating." Aw, shucks! There goes my plan for a glider-based airline!

Comment: @raptortech97 slightly more realistically, does that mean there can't be a blimp airline? (blimpline?)